# VSTO Merge to PDF

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop, office-2007

I have a VSTO Word addin that perform a mail merge, into a pdf, It must generate one pdf for each record each one of them with it's own name.

My code Works fine but it takes a lot of time generating each one PDF and it show some undesired visual efects.

There is another approach to perform this task ?

Here is my Code:

```
public void Mezclar(Word.Document Doc)
{
    decimal nRecords = Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount;
    for (int i = 1; i <= nRecords; i++)
    {
        Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = i;
        Doc.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = i;
        Doc.MailMerge.Destination = Word.WdMailMergeDestination.wdSendToNewDocument;
        Doc.MailMerge.Execute();
        Word.Document DocMezcla = this.Application.ActiveDocument;
        DocMezcla.SaveAs("d:\\clientes\\Pruebas" + i.ToString().Trim() + ".pdf", Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
        DocMezcla.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges, null, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

relying on vsto to do pdf conversion can be painful, and you cant do anything for visual. I would suggest to check out third party tool like Easy pdf sdk or ASPOSE

Comment: Tks, for your help, I'm  was looking at easy pdf, it has an API to perform mail merge ?

Comment: with easy pdf you will have to save file as docx and then convert to docx to pdf, however aspose.word can do mail merge